# How to get multiple fields at once?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have been typing this query

```
db.sInsert.find(
    {post_id:"28011986676_10155780942281677"},
    {comments_data: 1, _id:0}
)
```

And I got this result from MongoDB.

```
{
  "comments_data": {
    "id": "28011986676677",
    "comments": {
      "paging": {
        "cursors": {
          "after": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKePQT09",
          "before": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKEWXlPQT09"
        }
      },
      "data": [
        {
          "created_time": "2018-01-03T21:23:47+0000",
          "message": "Poor customer care service after became the  customer.I did my  re contract they send acknowledgement email confirmation after no followup.I called again and remains no proper response and action extremely worst customer care service.",
          "from": {
            "name": "Sun",
            "id": "102023391"
          },
          "id": "10155784116677"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How do I get the `post_id` and `message` only from `comments_data`? 
And i want to group by the `post_id`

Below is a sample of how my documents looks like in my mongoDB

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a43aa19d4b45e362428e2da"),
        "comments_data" : {
                "id" : "28011986676_10155780942281677",
                "comments" : {
                        "paging" : {
                                "cursors" : {
                                        "after" : "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKemIzSTZAN4TlRBeE5EWXlPQT09",
                                        "before" : "WTI5dGJXVnVk4TVRZAMk56YzZANVFV4TlRBeE5EWXlPQT09"
                                }
                        },
                        "data" : [
                                {
                                        "created_time" : "2018-01-03T21:23:47+0000",
                                        "message" : "Poor customer care service after became the Singtel customer.I did my          re contract they send acknowledgement email confirmation after no followup.I called again and remains no proper response and action extremely worst customer care service.",
                                        "from" : {
                                                "name" : "Sundararaju G",
                                                "id" : "1020391"
                                        },
                                        "id" : "10155780942281677_10155811924116677"
                                }
                        ]
                }
        },
        "post_id" : "28011986676_10155780942281677",
        "post_message" : "\"Singtel TV celebrated our 10th birthday with 10 awesome experiences for our customers! Each of our winners won a trip of a lifetime - from attending the Emmy Awards, getting a magical princess treatment at Disneyland, to catching a Premier League game live in London! We thank all our customers for your support and we look forward to more great years to come!\"",
        "reactions_data" : {
                "reactions" : {
                        "paging" : {
                                "cursors" : {
                                        "after" : "TVRBd01EQXpNVEF5T1Rje4TXc9PQZDZD",
                                        "before" : "TVRjNE56TTBBek56a3hNek14TWc9PQZDZD"
                                },
                                "next" : "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/280119866761677/reactions?access_token=EAA"
                        },
                        "data" : [
                                {
                                        "type" : "ANGRY",
                                        "id" : "1020573391",
                                        "name" : "Sundararaju Gh"
                                },
                                {
                                        "type" : "LIKE",
                                        "id" : "64721496",
                                        "name" : "Zhiang Xian"
                                }
                        ]
                },
                "id" : "28011986676_102281677"
        }
}
```

Another sample

```
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5a43aa19d4b45e362428e2ee"), "comments_data" : { "id" : "28011986676_10155778255601677",

 "comments" : { "paging" : { "cursors" : { "after" : "WTI5dGJXV5zZANVFV4TXpjM09UTTVNUT09" } }, 
"data" : [ { "created_time" : "2017-12-20T14:16:31+0000", "message" : "Putri Thang Michael Herman hahaha maret jg", "from" : { "name" : "Caterine Liang", "id" : "10153088743299160" }, "id" : "10155778255601677_101171677" }, { "created_time" : "2017-12-20T16:38:12+0000", "message" : "Pauline Chan", "from" : { "name" : "Nitin Aggarwal", "id" : "10153185412203152" }, "id" : "10155778255601677_10155779456916677" } ] } }, 

"post_id" : "28011986676_10155778255601677",
 "post_message" : "\"Peppa Pig and friends return to Singapore in a new musical LIVE show that\\u2019s bigger than ever with life-sized mascots. Singtel mobile subscribers enjoy exclusive priority sale and 15% off tickets to PEPPA & FRIENDS LIVE on Stage from 20 Dec \\u201817. Get your tickets at  now. T&Cs apply.\"",

 "reactions_data" : { "reactions" : { "paging" : { "cursors" : { "after" : "TVRBd01EQXpNREkwTVRc9PQZDZD", "before" : "TVRBd0c9PQZDZD" }, "next" : "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/28011986676_1601677/reactions?access_token=EAA" }, "data" : [ { "type" : "LIKE", "id" : "1263712690368750", "name" : "Alice Lo" }, { "type" : "LIKE", "id" : "130228537768890", "name" : "Gina Sangoy" }, { "type" : "LIKE", "id" : "478172222283410", "name" : "Jiamin Feng" }, { "type" : "LIKE", "id" : "10152186445293439", "name" : "Ann Wong" }, { "type" : "LIKE", "id" : "164905927597888", "name" : "ស្រីនាថ ពោធិ៍សាត់" }, { "type" : "LIKE", "id" : "694456787260426", "name" : "Lim Kian Heng" }, { "type" : "LIKE", "id" : "135201790538289", "name" : "Anasta Clara" }, { "type" : "LIKE", "id" : "10154040401150853", "name" : "Jacqueline Salim JingYuan" }, { "type" : "LIKE", "id" : "1428497527466013", "name" : "Izhan Sawalha" }, { "type" : "LIKE", "id" : "10152590923001843", "name" : "Ellena Liu" }, { "type" : "LIKE", "id" : "28011986676_1077" } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command ...

```
db.sInsert.find(
    {post_id:"28011986676_10155780942281677"},
    {'comments_data.comments.data.message': 1, _id:0}
)
```

... will return:

```
{
    "comments_data" : {
        "comments" : {
            "data" : [ 
                {
                    "message" : "Poor customer care service after became the  customer.I did my  re contract they send acknowledgement email confirmation after no followup.I called again and remains no proper response and action extremely worst customer care service."
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

In the document you supplied, the path to message is: `comments_data.comments.data.message` so that's the correct path to use in the projeciton argument to the `find()` method.

If the desired output is *only* message, in the sense of flattening the response to remove the intermediate levels, then this command ...

```
db.sInsert.aggregate([
  { $match: {post_id: {"$eq": "28011986676_10155780942281677" } } },
  { $project: {'message': '$comments_data.comments.data.message', _id:0} },
])
```

... will read the same data but will reshape the output into this:

```
{
    "message" : [ 
        "Poor customer care service after became the  customer.I did my  re contract they send acknowledgement email confirmation after no followup.I called again and remains no proper response and action extremely worst customer care service."
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi! it does shows only the 'message' out. but why do i have duplicates results?

Comment: Can you explain what "i have duplicates results" means? There's nothing in your original question about duplicate results.

Comment: sorry. cause when i run the command you provide, i have 20 results of the message " poor customer care service and etc" , but actually i still have other message in the comments data under the same post id, but it does not print out

Comment: That suggests that there are 20 documents in `db.sInsert` which have `post_id= "28011986676_10155780942281677"`. If you re run the command but remove `_id:0` from the `$project` clause you'll see 20 separate documents each of which has a different `_id`. The `$match` clause controls which documents are selected and the `$project` clause controls what data is selected from each document. The `$project` clause is successfully limiting the output to `message` and if you want to limit the result to a single document then you'll need to create a `$match` clause which matches a single document.

Comment: Thanks! so i have to do something like this ?

db.sInsert.aggregate([
  { $match: {post_id: {"$eq": "28011986676_10155780942281677" } } },
  { $match: {'message': '$comments_data.comments.data.message', _id:0} },
])

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do there but that command looks incorrect. With so little information to go on I'm really only guessing. This is starting to feel like a separate question. Here's the information which would be useful: (1) provide at least two sample documents from your collection (if the docs are large then cut them down to the minimal set of fields relevant to your question); (2) describe what you are trying to acheive (ideally you would provide an example docuemnt showing your desired result); (3) describe what you have tried and any issues you have encountered.

Comment: I have add sample of one of my documents in my mongoDB at the question area. I trying to achieve by showing just post_id and its 'message' at the comments_data.

Comment: i have tried
 db.sInsert.find({}, {post_id:1, 'comments_data.comments.data.message': 1, _id:0})


It does show post_id and the message from the comments data. But i want to group by post_id.

an example. i tried using this query 
db.sInsert.find({}, {'post_id:"28011986676677"', 'comments_data.comments.data.message': 1, _id:0})

I am experiencing error of 
2018-01-27T12:28:43.116+0800 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing : after property id @(shell):1:68

Comment: If you are finding by `post_id` then every document you find has the **same** `post_id` i.e. the grouping is implicit.So, I still cannot understand what you are trying to do. All I can offer at this stage is to repeat my [earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48437446/how-to-get-multiple-fields-at-once/48438319?noredirect=1#comment83885098_48438319) ... _This is starting to feel like a separate question. Here's the information which would be useful: (1) provide at least two sample documents from your collection (if the docs are large then cut them down to the minimal set of ..._

Comment: Hi, i have added 2 sample of my documents already. And i think i have provided  describing what i are trying to acheive (ideally you would provide an example document showing your desired result);  describing what i have tried and any issues you have encountered